# How to solve a hash function?

Tags: hash, passwords

I am totally lost on the below question and was wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction on here.

"Consider the hash function h(i) = (i + 5) mod 7, and suppose it is used in an implementation of the S/Key protocol. Let the seed be value 0, and suppose that the first password the user returns after the initialization step is 4.

What password does the user return on the third login counting the first login password as 4."

Any ideas?

Comment: Start by reading what the S/Key protocol does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/KEY

Comment: I read this. After reading this my instinct was to do...h(4) = (i + 5) mod 7. Is that correct? After 3 login counts, I get that the password is 5.

Comment: Either this - h(4) = (4+5) mod 7, h(2) = (2+5) mod 7 which gives me 0 or one more step which is h(0) = (0+5) mod 7 which gives me 5.

Comment: You need to *reverse* that hash function. So find out what input leads to an output of 4. Then find the input that leads to that one.

Comment: @Thilo, is this right? h(6) = (6 + 5) mod 7 = 4 
h(1) = (1 + 5) mod 7 = 6
h(3) = (3 + 5) mod 7 = 1

Comment: Confirmed this is correct. Thanks!